# Higher Algebra by Hall & Knight: Chapter 1, Art 16, Example 3

Tags: algebra-precalculus, symmetric-polynomials

This is a solved example from Higher Algebra by Hall and Knight. There are a few steps missing so I can't understand the continuity of the solution.

**Chapter 1, Ratio, Art 16, Example 3**

Solve the Equations
$$ax + by + cz = 0, \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

$$x + y + z = 0, \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

$$bcx +cay + abz = (b-c) (c-a) (a-b), \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

From (1) and (2) by cross multiplication,

$$\frac{x}{b-c} = \frac{y}{c-a} = \frac{z}{a-b} = k,\ \text {suppose;}$$

$$\therefore x = k(b-c), y = k(c-a), z = k(a-b)$$.

Substituting in (3),

$$k \ [bc(b-c) + ca(c-a) + ab(a-b)] = (b-c)(c-a)(a-b), \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

[OP's Note: I have understood till here, and I can't figure out how the authors derived the equation given in the next line.]

$$k \ [-(b-c)(c-a)(a-b)] = (b-c)(c-a)(a-b), \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

$$\therefore \ k=-1$$

whence: $$x=c-b,\ y=a-c,\ z=b-a$$

How is $(4)$ reduced to $(5)$?

Comment: It may be a small consolation, but on page 438, Chap. XXXIV, Art. 523, on Vandermonde determinants is the identity $ \Sigma\, bc(b-c) = -(b-c)(c-a)(a-b)$ which is a special case of Vandermonde.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try the other way around: expand the parentheses in (5).

Comment: Whether I try to expand (4) into (5) or the other way around I get the following equation:

$$k \ [a^2 (b-c) + b^2 (c-a) + c^2 (a-b)] = (b-c) (c-a) (a-b)$$

So, how do I continue?

Comment: Yes, so they agree, don't they?

Comment: That's true, but if this wasn't a "solved example", I wouldn't have (5), so I would be forced to reduce (4) into (5). So what is the mathematical manipulation I need to do to turn (4) into (5)?

Comment: Just expand both sides. Then you will see this intermediate identity you found. Probably it would be best to insert it into the book as step (4.5)

Comment: Oh yes... If I expand both the LHS and RHS of (4) I get $k = -1$

So, that's a less complicated way of solving the problem, so thanks a lot. Just that it doesn't help me understand what the authors were smoking when they jumped from (4) to (5) and then to $k = -1$.

Comment: (5) is a way through formulas to say "if you expand both sides, you will find the abc part of LHS of (4) is just the minus RHS (5).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to see how the identity arises.

If we translate $a,b,c$ by $x$, the expression (without $k$) on the LHS of $(4)$ becomes
$$
p(x)=(x+b)(x+c)(b-c)+(x+c)(x+a)(c-a)+(x+a)(x+b)(a-b).
$$
However, $p$ is a constant polynomial, because the coefficient of $x$ is $(b+c)(b-c)+(c+a)(c-a)+(a+b)(a-b)=0$, and the coefficient of $x^2$ is $(b-c)+(c-a)+(a-b)=0$. Therefore $p(0)=p(-a)$, i.e.
$$
bc(b-c)+ca(c-a)+ab(a-b)=-(a-b)(c-a)(b-c).
$$

Comment: @Somos Sorry, I don't follow. What's your point?

Comment: Thanks, I presume this concept will make a lot more sense to me when I reach the chapter on polynomials. I have just begun Chapter 1.

Comment: For your information, in Hall and Knight, Chapter XXII, Art. 310, p. 254 is this: _Example_. Prove that $$\frac{(x-b)(x-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)} + \frac{(x-c)(x-a)}{(b-c)(b-a)} + \frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{(c-a)(c-b)} = 1.$$